# Native binding Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.mac

I am trying to make native binding for Webrtc.a native library on mac when I include the binding library as reference to my Xamarin.Mac project I get this error : /MMP: Error MM5109: Native linking failed with error code 1.
I followed all these steps
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/

Comment: Note that the link applies iOS only. macOS is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to dig into the build details on your project to see the specific error. It means we invoked clang to build the native launcher and it returned errors (very likely associated to the native library being bound).

You can find the build log via: View -> Pads -> Errors then selecting the "Build Output" button.

Comment: Yes I checked that and I found this message:      Id: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: I think that because of using wrong static lib(.a file) and that file is for IOS not Mac

Comment: You can use file foo.a and otool -L foo.a to poke at your static lib to see what's up. But that seems likely.